# Spring expression Language - Call getter

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-el

Suppose I have a class MyClass as follows.

package com.classes.blabla;

```
public class MyClass
{

  String myVar;

public setMyVar(String myVar)
{
  this.myVar = myVar;
}

public String getMyVar()
{
  return myVar;
}

}
```

Now my question: How can I reference to the getter of MyClass using Spring Expression Templating???

Is it something like :

```
String value =  "I am a String #{(com.classes.blabla.MyClass).getMyVar()}"
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Regards,
Horace

Comment: Can you explain the context in which you are trying to use this? You need to reference an instance of the class, not just it's name.

Comment: Thanks for your help Gary. The context i am trying to use this is that I have a properties file with a string declared in it, for example: my.string="I am a string in which a replacement should occur #{(com.classes.blabla.MyClass).getMyVar()}".

Answer (score 3):

It's still not clear exactly what you are trying to do, but I'll make some assumptions and maybe we can get further along. If you have ...

```
<bean id="foo" class="com.classes.blabla.MyClass">
    <property name="myVar" value="bar"/>
</bean>
```

Then, you can use

```
< .... value="#{foo.myVar}" ... />
```

In other words, you need an `instance` of `MyClass` before you can extract a value from it.

If you have a property `my.property=abc #{foo.myVar} xyz`, you can use

```
< .... value="${my.property}" ... />
```

and the value will become `abc bar xyz`

Comment: Hi Gary, Thx for your support. In the example you have given, the expressions and properties values are resolved at compile time. But my goal is rather to let those values be resolved at runtime. In other words, the value I want to put into the "my.property" is not known at compile time. It is determined at runtime, saved in myVar, so that it can be accessed with new MyClass().getMyVar(). That is why I tried that:                              my.property=abc #{instanceOfMyClass.getMyVar()} xyz. Hope it is clear now. If not I will give you a code snippet. Thank you again

Comment: Sorry - it's still not clear - and my example is NOT resolved at compile time, it's resolved during context initialization. Please update your question with much more detail, so I don't have to guess; thanks.

Comment: I guess the real question is who calls `setMyVar()`, and when. You can always use the `SpEL` infrastructure (`EvaluationContext`, `SpelExpression` etc) programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
String value =  "I am a String #{(com.classes.blabla.MyClass).getMyVar()}"
```

This `(com.classes.blabla.MyClass).getMyVar()` is used for static functions .

Here bean of  Myclass is not used .

Below will work.

`"I am a String #{myClassBean.getMyVar()}"` will do